# Azure Native Application Common Authentication

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to acquire an access token for a user by using the common endpoint with a Native Application. I've tried both login.windows.net/common/OAuth2/Authorize and 
login.windows.net/common as the authority for the AuthenticationContext.

Here is the function I am using:

```
authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientID, redirectUri, PromptBehavior.Auto);
```

Here are the permissions for my application:

Windows Azure Active Directory: Access the directory as the signed-in user

Windows Azure Service management API: Access Azure Service Management as organization

When I try and authenticate I'm able to login in, but then I get the error:

AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '{client ID}'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

I can log in just fine using:

https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}/OAuth2/Authorize

but I want the user to be able to log in without knowing what their tenant ID is. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you are not able to use the common endpoint with a Microsoft Account which is what I was doing. You are only allowed to use an Azure Active Directory Account.

Comment: Yeah well since you can add a Microsoft account to multiple directories which one would it log you into?

Comment: Exactly, and I didn't know that back then so I figured I'd post it here in case anyone else doesn't know.

Comment: Certain Microsoft client ids (e.g. `1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2`) let you do this. Once logged in, you can use the resulting token to query the `https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2014-01-01` endpoint to get a list of *all* the tenants the user belongs to (and there's a short time window in which you can parlay your access token into tokens for any or all of those tenants without further user prompts). This seems to be how Azure Powershell and Visual Studio discover all your tenants and subs. Frustratingly there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with your own apps.