# Azure AD authentication failing when using ms live accounts other than my AAD acount

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I trying to read user data from their Microsoft live account. I have written code as below:

```
    public void GetUserData(){
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/");
        var result = _authenticationContext
                .AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", "<my client/app ID>", "<redirect URI>", new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession))
                .Result;    
        var accessToken = result.AccessToken;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",accessToken);
        var userResponse = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/").Result;

        //DO SOMTHING WITH DATA
    }
```

my code is working fine when I used my AAD credentials, but when I used my personal account it is giving the following error.

> AADSTS50020: User account 'XXXX@outlook.com' from identity provider
>   'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot
>   access the application 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' in that
>   tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the
>   tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active
>   Directory user account.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728455/aadsts50020-error-when-authenticating-user-with-live-com-based-account). could someone help me out?

Comment: Have you added the personal live account in your azure active directory?

Comment: check this link out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255819/azure-native-application-common-authentication

Comment: @Wayne Yang, not added any account to the azure ad. I want my app  working for any live account.

Comment: Then you have to use MSAL + AAD v2.0 endpoints instead of ADAL + v1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview

Comment: Hi, @sitchie ,You shouldn't just use Azure AD to achieve this. This is Azure AD B2B, you need invite users in to your directory and use v2.0 endpoint to authentication. According to your request, I suggest you use Azure AD B2C to achieve this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v1 endpoints require that the user is a member in a directory.

You should probably use the v2.0 endpoints for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview

If you expect only consumer MS accounts to login, you can specify the authorize URL as:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Answer (score 1):

First, for the error massage in your question, you need to add the live account into your directory first and then try to use Azure AD v2 endpoint to authenticate. **You can not sign in the app with the external account which was not in that directory**.

I assume that you want any Microsoft live account can use your app.

Based on this requirement, I suggest you can use [**Azure AD B2C**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) to achieve this. Azure AD B2C can enables your application to authenticate with any Microsoft account. You can add Microsoft Account as a social identity providers. So that any live accounts can sign up and sign in your App through Azure AD B2C.

You can see more details about Providing sign-up and sign-in to consumers with Microsoft accounts [in this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Though you can't use MS Graph API to get info on user when using B2C right? This really just sounds like the optimal scenario for v2.0 + consumers endpoint.

Comment: Hi,@jununas, Right,  I also agree with your opinion.